# Clarify the difference and connection of canvas, frame, pane and panel

Tags: java

I'm quite confused and I when I try to find an answer with google I get bombarded with tutorials.

- What is the purpose of each one?
- How are they connected?
- What is the purpose of the connection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- In java canvas is area used to draw something by java graphics. For ex. drawing an image or rectangle.
- Frame is used as JFrame(swing), a top level container which can contain canvas, panels, pane(DesktopPane, ScrollPane) etc..
- Panel or JPanel is a subcontainer used to contain textboxes, buttons, canvas etc.
- Jframe can contain multiple panels, but panel can't contain JFrame.

Textboxes, buttons can directly be added to  Jframe but it decreases flexibility, Suppose we want to hide a set of buttons from ui, then we need to hide them one by one from JFrame. If those text boxes are added to panel then we just need to hide that panel only. There are so many cases about using panel in jframe.

Comment: So the frame is the main thing and panels go on them and then you fill the panels?

Comment: Yes, you can assume these as Frame > Panel > other components

Comment: Cool, got it. I thought there was this crazy order with canvases being some key component after reading other peoples code. Thanks.